# Is anyone very familiar with the *. deps.json file?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a desktop program for the. NET6-WINDOWS platform,I modified the configuration of deps.

WinFormsApp2.deps.json：

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0": {
      "WinFormsApp2/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Newtonsoft.Json": "13.0.3"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "WinFormsApp2.dll": {}
        }
      },
      "Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.3": {
        "runtime": {
          "libs/Newtonsoft.Json.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "13.0.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "13.0.3.27908"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "libraries": {
    "WinFormsApp2/1.0.0": {
      "type": "project",
      "serviceable": false,
      "sha512": ""
    },
    "Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.3": {
      "type": "package",
      "serviceable": true,
      "sha512": "sha512-HrC5BXdl00IP9zeV+0Z848QWPAoCr9P3bDEZguI+gkLcBKAOxix/tLEAAHC+UvDNPv4a2d18lOReHMOagPa+zQ==",
      "path": "D:/wp",
      "hashPath": "newtonsoft.json.13.0.3.nupkg.sha512"
    }
  }
}
```

WinFormsApp2.runtimeconfig.json:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      }
    ],
    "additionalProbingPaths": [
      "libs"
    ]
  }
}
```

My program is now running normally.
How do I use relative paths in paths in libraries? I tried to modify it but it didn't take effect.

Comment: Please expand on exactly what "I tried to modify it but it didn't take effect." means. What did you try? What was the outcome and how did it differ from what you want?

Comment: I tried to change the path of Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.3 under the libraries node to a relative path, but the program ran and prompted that Newtonsoft.Json.dll could not be found